# How does quantum memory work using atoms?

Tags: photonics, quantum-memory

I was trying to learn quantum memory and went through some papers, websites, etc.

The current understanding I have (which I'm not sure is right) is this: Two photons are prepared together which are said to be entangled, one of the photons will interact with an atom and the state of the atom changes according to the what state the photon was in (hence, storing the memory?)

Is that correct? If not, where did I go wrong? and what is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. For implementing quantum memory, you don't really need entangled qubits. In essence, quantum memory is just storing a quantum state for future use.

Comment: that seems like a possible way to do it, but without further context and references is hard to answer this question sensibly

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be thinking about "quantum memory" like it is one specific thing and there is only one specific way it can happen.

In reality, what you describe is a valid notion of quantum memory.

Another popular one, involving the element Yb, is this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04195.